# Perfect events in a random world?

Tags: bias

I have a friend. They believe that God exists because they have experienced a large amount of 'perfect coincidences', or rather, events that are too perfect to be coincidences.

What kind of cognitive bias/fallacy is this? (They assure that it is not the [Availability Heuristic](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Availability_heuristic) because they remember all coincidences that happened, even the unremarkable ones, but I am not inclined to believe this) Is it confirmation bias? Focusing effect?

Please help.

Comment: Without knowing the specifics of observations made which made him decide these are 'perfect coincidences', it is hard to tell. But, [selection bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_bias), in particular 'sampling bias', also comes to mind. If you only include your own experience as a sample, and do not reflect on likelihood of events happening by random chance, then you might unintentionally succumb to selection bias.

Comment: The [observer selection effect](https://wiki.lesswrong.com/wiki/Observation_selection_effect) also seems relevant, which I would classify as a particular form of selection bias (although I am not certain).

Comment: @Buddha i think what your friend is describing are called a synchronicities. it's a jungian term referring to meaningful coincidences.

Comment: Similar to: [Term for the tendency to relate events that occurred in proximity?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/26192/7001)